# Route AngularJS App Root to Subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm working through the [Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) and was curious, if I didn't want to specify the subdirectory in the browser (e.g. just using `http://localhost:8000/` instead of `http://localhost:8000/app`), how can I do that?  I tried adding this to the `$routeProvider` step but I am clearly doing something wrong as I just keep getting the root `Index of /` tree

Comment: You are getting a Directory list instead of your app?

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez, kind of.  If I hit `http://localhost:8000/`, I get the directory list.  If I hit, `http://localhost:8000/app`, I get the app as the tutorial indicates.  What I'm looking to do is remove the need for the `/app` as it seems unnecessary for this app, and will help me for another app I'm building.

Comment: look at the server side routing and adjust accordingly